# How to disable SQL wrapper in Superset SQL Lab?

Tags: sql-server, apache-superset

Is it possible to disable SQL wrapper in Superset SQL Lab?
My SQL Server syntax query is not working because of that.
For example I want to use `#temp` table, but `inner_qry` ruins it.

Source SQL, which works fine

```
SELECT
GTD = GETDATE()
INTO #tmp 

SELECT
*
FROM #tmp
```

Raw SQL, which fails

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM (SELECT
GTD = GETDATE()
INTO #tmp 

SELECT
*
FROM #tmp) AS inner_qry
```

Superset version 0.37.2.

Comment: Have you seen [Cannot created temp table in redshift DB #3524](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/3524)? While this issue was created wrt. Redshift it applies to all SQL platforms that support temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible.

Can you rewrite your query to use `WITH` instead of a temporary table? Then it should work:

```sql
WITH tmp AS (SELECT GTD = GETDATE())
SELECT * FROM tmp
```

I never used SQL Server before, but I tested a simple query in Postgres and it works when wrapped:

```sql
WITH tmptable AS (SELECT * FROM events)
SELECT * FROM tmptable
```

Became:

```sql
SELECT ts AS ts,
       topic AS topic,
       value AS value
FROM
  (WITH tmptable AS
     (SELECT *
      FROM events) SELECT *
   FROM tmptable) AS expr_qry
LIMIT 1000
```

Which is valid.